# Stale JNLP files for <extension> (since Java 9?)

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-9

The JNLP file of my Java Web Start application contains an `<extension href="...">` tag in `<resources>` to reference a second JNLP file, which in turn references let’s say common resources. No problem with this until now (I think).

However with Java 9 (build 9.0.1+11) when starting the JNLP file some of the resources referenced in the second JNLP file cannot be loaded, because they do not exist anymore. This is because Java Web Start still has a stale version of that JNLP (in its cache) referencing e.g. "foo-1.2.jar" (which does not exist anymore), whereas the current version of the JNLP references "foo-1.3.jar".

Is this a Java 9 bug or am I missing something?

**Update 1:** As these common (or shared) resources are not updated very often, I am now unsure if this problem may have already been there before Java 9.

**Update 2:** On second thought, maybe the problem is that I do not specify a href on the jnlp element. While on purpose in the first JNLP (because there are application-desc arguments inserted at runtime which would be lost on reload), it's kind of accidental in the second JNLP.

---

The first JNLP looks like this (please note the extension element):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<jnlp
    spec="6.0+"
    codebase="https://example.com/158"
>
    ...
    <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
    <resources>
        <java version="9.*" java-vm-args="-Xmx800m --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.dnd=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <java version="1.8*" java-vm-args="-Xmx800m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="foo-20171018-client.jar" main="true"/>
        <extension href="https://example.com/shared/shared.jnlp"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="foo.bar.Baz"><argument>sessionKey</argument><argument>12</argument></application-desc>     
</jnlp>
```

The second JNLP looks like this (referencing foo...jar):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<jnlp
    spec="6.0+"
    codebase="https://example.com/shared"
>
    ...
    <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
    <resources>
        <java version="9.*" java-vm-args="-Xmx800m --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.dnd=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <java version="1.8*" java-vm-args="-Xmx800m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="foo-1.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="jhall-2.0.02.jar"/>
        <jar href="jmf-2.1.1.e.jar"/>
        <jar href="forms-1.2.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Java application cache (cached applications and applets, installed applications and applets)?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I am searching for a solution without having to tell a thousand customers, that they must now clear their cache in order to make my app work again. Even sticking with Java 8 is better than that.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the relevent part(s) of the JNLP file? AFAICT, you can reference a specific version with the `version` attribute of the JNLP file (see [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) - extension element): `version - The version of the additional extension jnlp file.`

Comment: The first JNLP lives in a different WAR than the second JNLP file. Until now it helped to be able to update the two WARs independently. This is partly because in reality it's not one but about 50 apps and they all reference the same shared WAR. But maybe this is the way to go: when the shared WAR changes, all the others must be updated too (their references). I will think about it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the version attribute could help, or how it would work even. Perhaps changing the href to a new JNLP file could also work? Been too long since I've worked with JNLP extensions to say anything with certainty. I do recall though, that once an extension has been downloaded (the JARs), it will never be downloaded again (at least not if the cache isn't cleared). So changing the versions of the JARs referred to, won't make it that the updated JARs are downloaded again. Again, been a long time for me so take that for what it is.

Comment: *They where updated, thus have now other names (like "foo-1.3.jar" instead of "foo-1.2.jar"). Java Web Start obviously still has an old version of that JNLP.* Could you explain this part of your question better.

Comment: @nullpointer I hope it’s clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JNLP specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jnlp-9-mrel6-eval-spec/index.html) - *6 Downloading and Caching of Resources*:

> 6.5.3 Managing the Cache
>
> The JNLP Client is responsible for managing the cache of downloaded
>   resources. The JNLP Client must make sure that the following invariant
>   is maintained:
>
> > Resources belonging to a particular application are never removed from the cache while the application is running.
>
> This rule makes sure that the application developer can make
>   assumptions about resources being in the cache while the application
>   is running. In particular, all resources that are eagerly downloaded
>   are going to be available locally in the cache during the entire
>   program execution.
>
> **The exact policy and algorithms used to manage the cache are
>   implementation-dependent.** A reasonable policy might be to first clear
>   out resources that are marked lazy before the ones marked eager.
>
> The JNLP Client can also manage extensions in any way it sees fit.
>   **They can be uninstalled at any given point or be kept around
>   permanently.** If the extension uninstaller is invoked, then another
>   request for the extension will require it to be downloaded again and
>   the extension installer to be rerun.

I highlighted the relevant bits that could apply in your situation. What I think happens here is that once your extension is downloaded into the cache, it is never updated on changes in the JNLP extension.

What you can do is version the JNLP `href`, i.e. start with `https://example.com/shared/shared-1.0.jnlp` and update the version if the contents change (`https://example.com/shared/shared-1.1.jnlp`, ...).

Or you can work with the `version` attribute of the extension.

Comment: On second thought, maybe the problem is that I do not specify a href on the jnlp element. While on purpose in the first JNLP (because there are application-desc arguments inserted at runtime), it's kind of accidental in the second JNLP.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing experience so far, Java 9 pretty much never gets the new JNLP. I must clear the cache, which as noted above, we cannot expect users to do. I don't see how changing the HREF is a solution as that will break every desktop link. Works fine if users go to an HTML page and re-click an ICON, which we would have changed to be the new HREF. But this is not a solution. I am currently considering this a Java 9 Java Web Start bug, and I hope they fix it soon. I will post a bug report, if one is not already there. Looking now.

Comment: Did you try `<update check="always" policy="always"/>`?

BTW: Changing the href was meant for a second JNLP file which was referenced from the first. The second JNLP should not be linked from the desktop. It does not represent an app, just shared libraries.